# Why git-flow is fast forwarding my feature branch merge?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm starting to use and learn about git-flow. By reading this article https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/git-flow/ it states that every feature branch merge will use --no-ff parameter to `git merge` which makes every sense considering the purpose of a feature branch.

The problem is that I'm testing git-flow in an empty repo and I can't figure out why the merges from a feature branch using the command `git flow feature finish "feature-name"` is always using fast forwarding.

I can't imagine a reason to why one should fast forward a feature branch. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a case, where `git-flow` doesn't uses `--no-ff` indeed:
[Look at GitHub issue #100 comment from Vincent Driessen](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/100#issuecomment-769968):

```
By design, git-flow uses the --no-ff option when merging  
in order to record that the commits belong together historically. 
However, when the feature branch contains only a single commit,
the extra merge commit does not add anything and only complicates 
the branch tree needlessly.
So for single-commit branches, fast-forward merges are being made 
as if the commit was done on develop directly.
```

It should be [this line of code #315](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-feature#L315):

```
if [ "$(git rev-list -n2 "$DEVELOP_BRANCH..$BRANCH" | wc -l)" -eq 1 ]; then
    git_do merge --ff "$BRANCH"
```